# How to iterate multiple http request's and solve a promise until of end of loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im have a request loop what send a image or multiple images at a promise and resolve returning "true" boolean value ¿the problem? the promise is resolved before ends of loop and the request is like "background" my question is "How to await the end of loop for to resolve the promise"? im try using async await at promise but does not working

```js
export const sendQuestionArray = (questionArr) => {
  return new Promise( async(resolve, reject) => {
    await questionArr.map((question) => {
      const formSend = new FormData()
      formSend.append('idAsignacion', question.question_id)
      formSend.append('pregunta', question.question)
      formSend.append('respuesta', question.value ? 'CUMPLE' : 'NO_CUMPLE')
      formSend.append('imagenes', JSON.stringify(question.photo))
      formSend.append('comments', question.comments)
      globalApi.post('/api-agv/audit/set_answer_audit', formSend)
    })
    resolve(true)
  })
}
```

Thanks for the asks

Answer (score 0):

You can await till POST request ends on each iteration (for each question).
Make sure your `globalApi.post` returns `Promise<any>`.

```js
export const sendQuestionArray = async questionArr => {
    for (const question of questionArr) {
        const formSend = new FormData()
        formSend.append('idAsignacion', question.question_id)
        formSend.append('pregunta', question.question)
        formSend.append('respuesta', question.value ? 'CUMPLE' : 'NO_CUMPLE')
        formSend.append('imagenes', JSON.stringify(question.photo))
        formSend.append('comments', question.comments)
        await globalApi.post('/api-agv/audit/set_answer_audit', formSend) // If 'post' method returns Promise
    }
    return true // will happen only after all requests
}
```

By the way: you don't need to use `Promise` constructor and `async/await` at the same time, async method always returns promises.

If you need to wait till all requests ends, just call `sendQuestionArray` with `await` keyword:

```js
// elsewhere in code
const result = await sendQuestionArray(questionArr)
console.log(result) // 'true', printed only after request sequence
```